# In ASA stored procedure how to view the existing SP using commands

Tags: sybase-asa

In ASA database What is the command to view the existing stored procedure code in command prompt?

Pls help me.

Thanks in advance.
Version ASA 9.0

Answer (score 0):

sp_helptext 'dbo.procedure_name'